# Libreoffice writer is missing its icon. Where should I put a replacement?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher, libreoffice, icons

The other libreoffice programs all have their icons in place but I get the 'blank icon' icon in unity's launcher. Any idea of the directory I should place a replacement icon or how I can get it back? I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice* && sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```

but it still shows up blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the launcher icons are tied to a *.desktop file and it seems like there are *.desktop files in /usr/share/applications and in ~/.local/share/applications.  I assume the .local version is used if it exists.  So I deleted (renamed really) the libreoffice-writer.desktop file in my .local folder and rebooted.  All is working again.

Comment: That fixed it! No reboot required for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In a bug report probably: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/874031

Comment: I had been searching for it but could not find it. Thank you!