# Thumbnails for certain formats not appearing in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice, thumbnails

`.odt` and `.odb` files do not have an icon in Nautilus and some of my older documents are missing their thumbnails, all of which are either `.odt` or `.odp`.

I just purged and reinstalled LibreOffice today... could this be the reason why?

I am on Ubuntu 11.10, using LibreOffice 3.4  340m1(Build:402) that comes by default in the repos.

Here's what I see for these formats:

[image]

Comment: Can you give more information? what you see? wich ubuntu version and where you have install libreoffice (from repo or any ppa)? In my computer I see this for example: http://imagebin.org/207375

Comment: Of course...I tend to be vague sometimes, sorry about that. I'll add it to my original post as an edit.

Comment: I have found look around the solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/80055/13038 Seem work for that user

Comment: My .local/share/applications folder doesn't have anything tied to LibreOffice. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have LibreOffice documents in Nautilus while using Ubuntu 11.10 you need to install an extension to it since those are not supported by default.

The only one I know of is `ooo-thumbnailer` from [this](https://launchpad.net/~flimm/+archive/ooo-thumbnailer) PPA, it can be installed using these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flimm/ooo-thumbnailer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ooo-thumbnailer
```

When its done installing you should need to log off or restart Nautilus with `nautilus -q`.

It should be safe to use this PPA but you should always remember there are no warranties using PPAs.

For more information on what are PPAs and risks involved in using one please have a look at the following posts:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I installed ooo-thumbnailer and restarted my computer. Still no icons. Thank you for your help, though. Do you think maybe some files are missing from my LO install?

Comment: @RyanMcClure Newest release (0.5) works fine for me on 12.04.2 LTS and with LO 3.6.5 installed. Did you install LO manually or from the repos/a PPA?

Comment: Another option is the `libgsf-bin` package. It works for me in 14.04!